# Continuous random variable with density function

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

$X$ is a continuous random variable with p.d.f. $f(x) = c\space e^{-x} ; x > 1$. Find $P(X < 3|X > 2)$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the event $X\gt 2$, and $B$ be the event $X\lt 3$. We want $\Pr(B|A)$. By the definition of conditional probability, we have
$$\Pr(B|A)=\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(A)}\tag{1}.$$

We need to compute the probabilities on the right of Formula (1). We have
$$\Pr(A\cap B)=\int_2^3ce^{-x}\,dx=c(e^{-2}-e^{-3}).$$
Similarly, we have
$$\Pr(A)=\int_2^\infty ce^{-x}\,dx=ce^{-2}.$$
Finally, divide as per Formula (1).

**Remarks:** $1$. For completeness, we really should have computed $c$, even though ultimately it cancels. The constant $c$ is chosen so that $\int_0^\infty ce^{-x}\,dx=1$. Calculations shows this forces $c=1$.

$2.$ One can think of the answer as a mechanical calculation. However, there is much more to it than that. The random variable $X$ has an exponential distribution. Note that when we compute the answer, we find that
$$\Pr(B|A)=\frac{c(e^{-2}-e^{-3})}{ce^{-2}}=1-e^{-1}.$$
But $1-e^{-1}$ is just the probability that $X\le 1$.

So if the lifetime $X$ of some object is governed by the exponential distribution above, then the probability that $X$ lives less than $1$ additional year, **given** it has already lived $2$ years, is the same as the probability that an object fresh out of the box lives less than one year.

Objects whose lifetime is governed by an exponential distribution die but do not age. Typical are atoms of a radioactive isotope.

The phenomenon we have observed is called the **memorylessness property** of the exponential. If we knew that property, we could have instantly written $1-e^{-1}$ as our answer, with no computation.